# Реализация функции поиска в массиве

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Пишу функцию поиска элемента в массиве с использованием `generics`:

```
pos<T>(arr: array of T; element: T): integer;
var
    i: integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to high(arr) do
        if (arr[i] = element) then exit(i);
end;
```

Конечно же, на этапе сравнения получаю:

> Operator not applicable to this operand type

Можно ли как-то обойти это, реализовав универсальную функцию поиска в массиве? Не страшно, если массив при этом не сможет содержать в себе объектов.

Comment: В C# можно задавать ограничения для типов

Comment: А в JavaScript можно вот так просто брать и сравнивать.

Comment: Javascript имеет другой тип типизации.

Comment: Странно конечно, что вы не используете любимый PHP

Comment: Что поделать, хочу компилировать.

Comment: Вы же не компилятор

Answer (score 3):

Можете также обратить внимание на то, каким образом реализован метод `TList<T>.IndexOf` в `Generics.Collections`, поскольку он решает ту же самую задачу что и ваша. Принцип там использован следующий:

```
class function TTest.Pos<T>(needle: T; haystack: array of T): integer;
var c : IEqualityComparer<T>;
    idx : integer;
begin
    c := TEqualityComparer<T>.Default();

    for idx := 0 to high(haystack) do begin
        if c.Equals(haystack[idx], needle) then exit(idx);
    end;
    result := -1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [ограничения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323611/delphi-generics-type-constraint-ordinal-types) для generics

```
pos<T: IComparable>(arr: array of T; element: T): integer;
var
    i: integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to high(arr) do
        if (arr[i] = element) then exit(i);
end;
```

Comment: скомпилировали хоть?

Comment: @teran в смысле?

Comment: в прямом. компилировать кусок кода пробовали этот?

Comment: @teran Не пробовал